# Add new over lay for flutter bar code scan (barcode_scan)

Tags: flutter, barcode-scanner

In my app I have to add qr scanner and I have developed it using [barcode_scan](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan) package without any issue. But I need to change the scan overlay page. Still I could n't find a way to edit or add new scan overlay for it. Has anyone done this before, any clue would be appreciate?

Comment: Could you explain your problem in greater detail?  I am not sure what "Scan Overlay Page" actually means.

Is there any way you could include a code sample?

I use qr_mobile_vision package and it works perfectly on both Android and IOS without if statements.  Perhaps you might consider it.

Answer (score 0):

please try this package https://pub.dev/packages/last_qr_scanner

this package use AndroidView and UiKitView

```
class _QRViewState extends State<LastQrScannerPreview> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var androidView = AndroidView(
      viewType: 'last_qr_scanner/qrview',
      onPlatformViewCreated: _onPlatformViewCreated,
    );

    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      return androidView;
    }

    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      return UiKitView(
        viewType: 'last_qr_scanner/qrview',
        onPlatformViewCreated: _onPlatformViewCreated,
        creationParams: _CreationParams.fromWidget(0, 0).toMap(),
        creationParamsCodec: StandardMessageCodec(),
      );
    }
```

demo picture

[image]